# Where is he to go in?

Tags: grammar, future-tense, future-time

1. Where is he to go in?
2. Where is he going to go in?

Do these two basically mean the same? 
How is the be + to form usually used? Can you give some simple sentence examples?

Comment: How about: _"Where will he go in?"_ Sounds more natural to me. (Yours aren't wrong, though.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are similar, but not the same. The be+to form usually means that someone *should* do something, or that they are *required* to do something - for example, "You are to complete the form with a blue pen" means "You must use a blue pen when working on this form". The form is very formal, though - you would not use it when talking to a friend, or even to your child.

So the first sentence means "Where is he required to enter?", while the second means "Where will he enter?"